# compare alphabets in bash

Tags: string, compare

I want to compare the first alphabet(string) of a file in a given directory and once the comparison becomes true, the script meant to copy or move that particular file to another directory.

In this example I want to copy all those files which are greater than the alphabet "m" i.e as soon as the first alphabet from a file is greater than "m", assuming that a

Example of files to compare: mard_2002.dat, accd_2001.dat, mcck_1999.dat qddf_2010.dat

x="m"

for file in *.dat

do

t="$(echo $file | awk '{print substr($1,1,1)}')"

if [ "$t" > "$x" ]

then
  cp $file ./TEMP
  echo "now the file is compied"
else
 echo $file
fi
read pause
done

The above if [ "$t" > "$x" ] or if [ "$t" < "$x" ]  command seems to return always true. The script is only copy correctly when I use the equal sign, if [ "$t" = "$x" ], in this case it only copies those file which only begin with the alphabet "m".

Any comments please
Regards
Yacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOO=m

for FILE in `ls -1 [$FOO-z]*|grep -v "^$FOO"`
do
echo "Would do things to file $FILE"
done
```